# В текстовом поле Tkinter скролинг сжимает виджет в ширину - как исправить?

Tags: python, tkinter

Пишу приложение, в котором необходимо добавить Scrollbar. Сделал это, но теперь получается, что если привязать скролинг к собственно текстовой области (а не к фрейму, в котором она располагается), то область в рамке становится узкой, не растягиваясь по всему фрейму. Как исправить?

```
window = tk.Tk()

# создадим рамку, которая формирует область с "обучением" модели "вручную"
frame_training = tk.Frame(
    master=window, 
    relief=tk.RIDGE, 
    borderwidth=5)

# создадим ярлык с заголовком для текстового поля (оно ниже)
lbl_add_to_the_list = tk.Label(
    master=frame_training,
    text='Дополни список ответов шара',
    foreground='black',    
    bg='#E1D1E0',
    width=15, 
    height=5   
)

# данная область предназначена для внесения новых вариантов ответов
text_box_train = tk.Text(
    master=frame_training,
    width=90, 
    height=5, 
    bg='#EBF1F2',
    fg='black'
)

# создадим элемент кнопки Обучить шар 
button_train = tk.Button(
    master=frame_training,
    text='Обучить шар',
    width=15,
    height=2,
    bg='#B533FF',
    fg='yellow',
    activebackground='#C4B1C3'
)
# создадим элемент кнопки Очистить (для обучения шара) 
button_train_clear = tk.Button(
    master=frame_training,
    text='Очистить',
    width=15,
    height=2,
    bg='#B533FF',
    fg='yellow',
    activebackground='#C4B1C3')

# добавляем виджеты в сетку окна
frame_training.grid(
    column=0, row=1,
    columnspan=2,
    sticky='e') 

lbl_add_to_the_list.grid(
    sticky='nsew', columnspan=3)

text_box_train.grid(
    column=0, row=1,columnspan=3,
    sticky='e')

button_train.grid(
    row=3, column=0, sticky='e')
button_train_clear.grid(
    row=3, column=1, sticky='w', columnspan=2)

# лента прокрутки для текстового поля "обучения" шара 
scrollbar_train = tk.Scrollbar(text_box_train,                                 
                                 orient='vertical', 
                                  command=text_box_train.yview  
                                 )
scrollbar_train.grid(row=1, column=3, sticky='ns')                
text_box_train.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar_train.set)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Одним `grid` тут не обойтись, ибо в разных рядах вам нужна разная сетка. Опять же, способов уйма как достичь требуемого. Надо использовать вложенные фреймы. Можно на `pack`, можно и на `grid` (хотя лично я предпочитаю, где это возможно, использовать `pack`, выглядит, как по мне, понятнее, да и писанины меньше, если потребуется вдруг чего добавить/убрать/переставить).

Вот так это можно реализовать на `grid`:

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()

# создадим рамку, которая формирует область с "обучением" модели "вручную"
frame_training = tk.Frame(
    master=window, 
    relief=tk.RIDGE, 
    borderwidth=5)

# создадим ярлык с заголовком для текстового поля (оно ниже)
lbl_add_to_the_list = tk.Label(
    master=frame_training,
    text='Дополни список ответов шара',
    foreground='black',    
    bg='#E1D1E0',
    width=15, 
    height=5   
)

frame_training_text_with_scroll = tk.Frame(
    master=frame_training
)

# данная область предназначена для внесения новых вариантов ответов
text_box_train = tk.Text(
    master=frame_training_text_with_scroll,
    width=90, 
    height=5, 
    bg='#EBF1F2',
    fg='black'
)

# создадим элемент кнопки Обучить шар 
button_train = tk.Button(
    master=frame_training,
    text='Обучить шар',
    width=15,
    height=2,
    bg='#B533FF',
    fg='yellow',
    activebackground='#C4B1C3'
)
# создадим элемент кнопки Очистить (для обучения шара) 
button_train_clear = tk.Button(
    master=frame_training,
    text='Очистить',
    width=15,
    height=2,
    bg='#B533FF',
    fg='yellow',
    activebackground='#C4B1C3')

# добавляем виджеты в сетку окна
frame_training.grid(
    column=0, row=0,
    columnspan=2,
    sticky='nswe') 

window.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
window.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

lbl_add_to_the_list.grid(
    row=0, column=0, columnspan=2,
    sticky='nsew')

frame_training_text_with_scroll.grid(
    row=1, column=0, columnspan=2,
    sticky='news')
frame_training.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
frame_training.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
frame_training.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
    
text_box_train.grid(
    row=0, column=0,
    sticky='news')

frame_training_text_with_scroll.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
frame_training_text_with_scroll.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

button_train.grid(
    row=2, column=0, sticky='ew')
button_train_clear.grid(
    row=2, column=1, sticky='ew',)

# лента прокрутки для текстового поля "обучения" шара 
scrollbar_train = tk.Scrollbar(master=frame_training_text_with_scroll,                                 
                                 orient='vertical', 
                                  command=text_box_train.yview  
                                 )
scrollbar_train.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky='ns')                
text_box_train.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar_train.set)

text_box_train.insert(tk.END, "Line1\nLine2\nLine3\nLine4\nLine5\nLine6\nLine7\nLine8\n")

window.mainloop()
```

Или то же самое, используя `pack`:

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()

# создадим рамку, которая формирует область с "обучением" модели "вручную"
frame_training = tk.Frame(
    master=window, 
    relief=tk.RIDGE, 
    borderwidth=5)

# создадим ярлык с заголовком для текстового поля (оно ниже)
lbl_add_to_the_list = tk.Label(
    master=frame_training,
    text='Дополни список ответов шара',
    foreground='black',    
    bg='#E1D1E0',
    width=15, 
    height=5   
)

frame_training_text_with_scroll = tk.Frame(
    master=frame_training
)

# данная область предназначена для внесения новых вариантов ответов
text_box_train = tk.Text(
    master=frame_training_text_with_scroll,
    width=90, 
    height=5, 
    bg='#EBF1F2',
    fg='black'
)

frame_buttons = tk.Frame(
    master=frame_training
)

# создадим элемент кнопки Обучить шар 
button_train = tk.Button(
    master=frame_buttons,
    text='Обучить шар',
    width=15,
    height=2,
    bg='#B533FF',
    fg='yellow',
    activebackground='#C4B1C3'
)
# создадим элемент кнопки Очистить (для обучения шара) 
button_train_clear = tk.Button(
    master=frame_buttons,
    text='Очистить',
    width=15,
    height=2,
    bg='#B533FF',
    fg='yellow',
    activebackground='#C4B1C3')

# добавляем виджеты в сетку окна
frame_training.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

lbl_add_to_the_list.pack(fill=tk.X)

frame_training_text_with_scroll.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
    
text_box_train.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

frame_buttons.pack(fill=tk.X)
button_train.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.X, expand=True)
button_train_clear.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.X, expand=True)

# лента прокрутки для текстового поля "обучения" шара 
scrollbar_train = tk.Scrollbar(master=frame_training_text_with_scroll,                                 
                                 orient='vertical', 
                                  command=text_box_train.yview  
                                 )
scrollbar_train.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.Y)
text_box_train.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar_train.set)

text_box_train.insert(tk.END, "Line1\nLine2\nLine3\nLine4\nLine5\nLine6\nLine7\nLine8\n")

window.mainloop()
```

[image: -]